# kendo date input field need selection on date part

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

there is any possible method to get selection to date part in kendo date-input field while the date input control get focus?[image]

currently cursor in year part and not selected the year part.

I want like below one,

[image]

need focus on date part and selected.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this demo will help you.

**Working Demo:** https://dojo.telerik.com/OHuVAPiV

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dateinput").kendoDateInput({
      format: "dd-MM-yyyy"
    });
          
    $("#dateinput").on("focusin", function(e){
        const input = document.getElementById('dateinput');
        //input.focus();
        input.setSelectionRange(0, 3);              
        });
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.3.1207/styles/kendo.default-main.min.css" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    
    

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

<input id="dateinput" title="please enter date" style="width: 100%" />
```